# Loop through dynamic array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
  var arrPropertiesAndChannels = null, arrPrrp = null, arrLeftProp = null, arrMiddleDefault = null, arrRightProp = null;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            arrPropertiesAndChannels = { "props": [{ "prid": "61494", "prname": "Park Plaza Hotel Gurgaon", "pos": "1", "pinned": false, "display": true }, { "prid": "62998", "prname": "Lemon Tree City Center", "pos": "2", "pinned": false, "display": true }, { "prid": "62999", "prname": "Lemon Tree Hotel Udyog Vihar", "pos": "3", "pinned": false, "display": true }, { "prid": "78097", "prname": "Royal Retreat", "pos": "4", "pinned": false, "display": false }, { "prid": "78098", "prname": "SkRetreat", "pos": "5", "pinned": false, "display": false }, { "prid": "78099", "prname": "VBkRetreat", "pos": "6", "pinned": false, "display": false}], "chans": [{ "chid": "1", "chname": "FACEBOOK", "pos": "1" }, { "chid": "2", "chname": "TWITTER", "pos": "2" }, { "chid": "3", "chname": "NEWSLETTER", "pos": "3"}] };
            arrPrrp = arrPropertiesAndChannels.props;
            arrLeftProp = arrPrrp.slice(0, 0);
            arrMiddleDefault = arrPrrp.slice(0, 3);
            arrRightProp = arrPrrp.slice(3, 8);

        });


function navigRight() {
    var tempprid = '';



    $.each(arrMiddleDefault, function (i, data) {
        console.log(data.prid);
        if (data.pinned == false) {
            arrLeftProp.push(data);
            tempprid = data.prid;
            //console.log(tempprid);
            //break;
        }
    });



arrMiddleDefault = arrMiddleDefault.filter(function (el) {
        return el.prid !== tempprid;
    });

    arrMiddleDefault.push(arrRightProp.slice(0, 1));
    //console.log(arrMiddleDefault);
    //console.log(arrLeftProp);


    arrRightProp = arrRightProp.filter(function (el) {
        return el.prid !== arrRightProp.slice(0, 1)[0].prid;
    });

}

<div>
        <input type="button" value="<<" onclick="navigLeft()">
        <div id="dvTest">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value=">>" onclick="navigRight()">
    </div>
```

I have json data variable

```
arrPropertiesAndChannels ={ "props": [{ "prid": "61494", "prname": "Park Plaza Hotel Gurgaon", "pos": "1", "pinned": false, "display": true }, { "prid": "62998", "prname": "Lemon Tree City Center", "pos": "2", "pinned": false, "display": true }, { "prid": "62999", "prname": "Lemon Tree Hotel Udyog Vihar", "pos": "3", "pinned": false, "display": true }, { "prid": "78097", "prname": "Royal Retreat", "pos": "4", "pinned": false, "display": false }, { "prid": "78098", "prname": "SkRetreat", "pos": "5", "pinned": false, "display": false }, { "prid": "78099", "prname": "VBkRetreat", "pos": "6", "pinned": false, "display": false}], "chans": [{ "chid": "1", "chname": "FACEBOOK", "pos": "1" }, { "chid": "2", "chname": "TWITTER", "pos": "2" }, { "chid": "3", "chname": "NEWSLETTER", "pos": "3"}] };
```

by which we have

```
arrPrrp = arrPropertiesAndChannels.props;
arrLeftProp = arrPrrp.slice(0, 0);
console.log(arrLeftProp);
arrMiddleDefault = arrPrrp.slice(0, 3);
console.log(arrMiddleDefault);
arrRightProp = arrPrrp.slice(3, 8);
console.log(arrRightProp);
```

I have a button value is ">>". On click of this button, javascript  navigRight()  function calls ...in which first item of arrMiddleDefault is push into arrLeftProp array.This time first item is 
removed from arrMiddleDefault array and first item of arrRightProp is inserted into arrMiddleDefault array. First click of button ">>" console.log(data.prid) gives 61494,62998,62999 in 
navigRight() function. Second time console.log(data.prid) gives 61494,62998,undefined, Third time console.log(data.prid) gives 61494,undefined,undefined, Fourth time console.log(data.prid) gives undefined,undefined,undefined

Comment: Now check .. i explained this .. check this on your HTML Page using console.log in firbug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you call:

```
arrMiddleDefault.push(arrRightProp.slice(0, 1));
```

You are pushing an array onto the `arrMiddleDefault` array, when you really want to push the first element onto the `arrMiddleDefault` array.

You could use this instead:

```
arrMiddleDefault.push(arrRightProp.slice(0, 1)[0]);
```

But it could just as well be shortened to this:

```
arrMiddleDefault.push(arrRightProp[0]);
```

Similarly, where you have the following:

```
   return el.prid !== arrRightProp.slice(0, 1)[0].prid;
```

You could shorten it to:

```
   return el.prid !== arrRightProp[0].prid;
```